# R ggplot combine legends for colour and fill with different factor length

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot with data from an incomplete factorial design. Due to the design, I have different length for the manual scale for colour and the manual scale for fill. Thus, I get two legends. How could I delete one of them or even better combine them?

I have looked at those questions:

[Merge separate size and fill legends in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862027/merge-separate-size-and-fill-legends-in-ggplot)

[How to merge color, line style and shape legends in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140266/how-to-merge-color-line-style-and-shape-legends-in-ggplot/37140824#37140824)

[How to combine scales for colour and size into one legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060000/how-to-combine-scales-for-colour-and-size-into-one-legend)

However, the answers did not help me as they did not handle incomplete designs.

Here is some example data and the plot I produced so far:

```
#Example data 
Man1 <- c(25,25,30,30,30,30,35,35,40,40,40,40,45,45) 
Man2 <- c(25,25,30,30,40,40,35,35,40,40,30,30,45,45) 
DV <- c(24.8,25.2,29.9,30.3,35.2,35.7,34,35.1,40.3,39.8,35.8,35.9,44,44.8)
Data <- data.frame(Man1,Man2,DV)

#Plot 
ggplot(data = Data, aes(x = Man1, y = DV, group=as.factor(Man2), colour=as.factor(Man2))) +
  theme_bw()  +  
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "longdash") +  
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(1)) 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(x = Man1, y = DV, group=as.factor(Man2),   fill=as.factor(Man2)))  + 
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Man2", values=c('grey20', 'blue','grey20','tomato3', 'grey20'))  + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Man2", values=c('blue','tomato3'))
```

This gives me the following picture:

[ggplot of incomplete design with two legends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WurQ.png)

Could someone give me a hint how to delete one of the legends or even better combine them? I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the scale drops unused factor levels, which is relevant here because can only get lines for a couple of your groups.

You can use `drop = FALSE` to change this in the appropriate `scale_*_manual()` (which is for `fill` here).

Then use the same vector of colors for both the `fill` and `color` scales.  I usually make a named vector for this.

```
# Make vector of colors
colors = c("25" = 'grey20', "30" = 'blue', "35" = 'grey20', "40" = 'tomato3', "45" = 'grey20')

#Plot 
ggplot(data = Data, aes(x = Man1, y = DV, group=as.factor(Man2), colour= as.factor(Man2))) +
    theme_bw()  +  
    geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "longdash") +  
    geom_point(position = position_dodge(1))  +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(fill=as.factor(Man2)))  + 
    scale_colour_manual(name = "Man2", values = colors)  + 
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Man2", values = colors, drop = FALSE)
```

[image]
Alternatively, use `guide = "none"` to remove the `fill` legend all together.

```
ggplot(data = Data, aes(x = Man1, y = DV, group=as.factor(Man2), colour= as.factor(Man2))) +
    theme_bw()  +  
    geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "longdash") +  
    geom_point(position = position_dodge(1))  +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(fill=as.factor(Man2)))  + 
    scale_colour_manual(name = "Man2", values = colors)  + 
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Man2", values=c('blue','tomato3'), guide = "none")
```

[image]