# How to merge color and fill aes on same legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a chart where I need to combine both fill and colour on the same legend. The closest I have come to achieve this is the example below, but it introduces a square surrounding the line (see legend below for pce).  I have looked at [combine legends for color and shape into a single legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410908/combine-legends-for-color-and-shape-into-a-single-legend)
 and [how to merge color, line style and shape legends in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140266/how-to-merge-color-line-style-and-shape-legends-in-ggplot)

but their solutions does not seem to work for fill and colour. In this case I get this square surrounding the line (see legend below). I also don't want to have them all as squares as suggested in the answer to [combine merge color and fill legend into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138567/combine-merge-color-and-fill-legend-into-one).

```r
library(tidyverse)



econ_names <-c(
  "pce",    
  "pop",    
  "psavert",
  "uempmed",
  "unemploy"
  
)



some_fills <- c(NA, "#FFB400", "#FF4B00", "#65B800", "#00B1EA")
some_cols <- c("#003299", rep(NA,4))



names(some_fills)<- econ_names
names(some_cols)<- econ_names


ggplot(data = economics_long,aes(date,value01,col = variable,fill = variable))+
  geom_col(data = subset(economics_long,variable!="pce"))+
  geom_line(data = subset(economics_long,variable=="pce"), size = 1.05)+
  scale_colour_manual(values = some_cols)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = some_fills)+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: you want the square removed? or something else?

Comment: I wanted to remove the blue square but keep the line as suggested in the answer. I should probably have made that more explicit in the question. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by setting the linetype for the columns as follows:

```
ggplot(data = economics_long,aes(date,value01,col = variable,fill = variable))+
  geom_col(data = subset(economics_long,variable!="pce"), linetype = 0)+
  geom_line(data = subset(economics_long,variable=="pce"), size = 1.05)+
  scale_colour_manual(values = some_cols)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = some_fills)+
  theme_minimal()
```

which produces

[image: Output figure]

Comment: Thank you so much - what an elegant solution!