# R survminer::ggsurvplot duplicates legend when setting linetype

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, survival-analysis, legend-properties

Reproducible example:

```
require(Survival)
require(survminer)
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

a <- c(32,291,545, 44,3,792,352, 20,615,169, 61,156, 88,863,255, 33,132,5,
       63,8,964,831, 55,133, 12, 54,261,867, 17, 12,699,233,251,446, 43,223, 
       374, 75, 34, 69,120, 84,134,8,806,8, 48, 86,211, 2436, 61, 81, 87, 12, 
       838, 34, 17,141, 44,155,128,6, 29, 16, 16, 34,130,430,325, 41, 28, 53,
       32,291,545, 44,3,792,352, 20,615,169, 61,156, 88,863,255, 33,132,5,
       63,8,964,831, 55,133, 12, 54,261,867, 17, 12,699,233,251,446, 43,223,
       86, 54,3,630, 93,699, 25,746,6, 46, 22, 60,395,402,151, 26, 38,125, 
       75, 34, 69,120, 84,134,8,806,8, 48, 86,211, 2436, 61,
       191, 49, 59,6, 34, 56,2, 96, 422, 45, 70)

b <- sample(c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"), length(a), replace = T)
c <- sample(0:1, length(a), replace = T)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)

df$b <- factor(df$b, levels = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"))
avg <- survfit(Surv(time = a, event = c) ~ 1, data = df)
surv_b <- survfit(Surv(time = a, event = c) ~ b, data = df)
surv_comb <- list(surv_b, avg)

survminer::ggsurvplot_combine(
  surv_comb, 
  data = df,
  combine = TRUE,
  censor = FALSE,
  legend = "right",
  palette = c("orange", "steelblue", "seagreen", "black"),
  linetype = c(rep("solid",3), "dashed"),
  legend.title = element_blank(),
  legend.labs = c(levels(df$b), "avg")
)
```

The above code produces a chart with the legend duplicated as in the image below:
[image: ggsurvplot with duplicate legend]

If I comment out the linetype argument in ggsurvplot, the legend is there only once - but I would really like to use the dashed linetype for the average to distinguish it from the other curves. Would anyone know how to fix the code so that it is like in the image but with the colour legend only and the correct linetypes, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge color, line style and shape legends in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140266/how-to-merge-color-line-style-and-shape-legends-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `labs()` and use the same name for `color` and `linetype`:

```
p <- survminer::ggsurvplot_combine(
  surv_comb, 
  data = df,
  combine = TRUE,
  censor = FALSE,
  legend = "right",
  palette = c("orange", "steelblue", "seagreen", "black"),
  linetype = c(rep("solid",3), "dashed"),
  legend.title = element_blank(),
  legend.labs = c(levels(df$b), "avg")

p + labs(color = "lines", linetype = "lines")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, @andrew_reece, *exactly* what I was looking for! Appreciate your help.